# Access the request object from Express inside a Mongoose Plugin

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I have an API in ExpressJS and a middleware that gets executed before each endpoint controller:

```
app.use(segregationMiddleware);

app.get('/some-endpoint', controller1);
app.get('/some-endpoint-2', controller2);
```

The `segregationMiddleware` is used to look for some parameters in the request and then it calculates a value that then is stored in the request object as `req.locals.domain` so the controllers can access it.

In each Mongoose model, I define a field named `domain` using a Mongoose plugin (so I don't have to do it every time). That field is used to segregate my assets. This means that when the `segregationMiddleware` populates `req.locals.domain = 'foo'` for example, if I make a `model.find({})` I want to get only assets that have `{ domain: 'foo' }`. Same thing if I try to update, save, delete, and so.

Of course, I can just simply modify the query on each controller since I have accesso to `req`, but I need to do it every time and I need to remember it for finds, findAndUpdate, save, and soo... sooner or later I'm gonna forget it.

I can define some hooks in Mongoose that will modify the query using a plugin so it adds the `domain` constraint to the query so I don't have to do it in the controller BUT I don't have the current `req` object in the Mongoose plugin unless I pass it, and the only way that come to my mind is to abstract the DB methods in the plugin, so in the controller, I do something like this:

```
model.safeFind(req, query);
```

And in the plugin I define `safeFind` like:

```
safeFind = () => {
  const theRealQuery = Object.assign({}, query, { domain: req.locals.domain });
  return this.find(query);
}
```

BUT, in this way, I need to redefine each DB query function (find, findOne, update, save...) and I need to remember to use the safe methods. Then again, I'm going to forget it sooner or later.

Is there a way I can still use the regular Mongoose methods from the controller and have the plugin somehow modify the query for every method using the current `req` object?